# In React-Bootstrap 2.5.0 is there a way to put the Navbar.Brand next to the Navbar.Toggle?

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-nav

Currently, I have the following where the Navbar.Toggle is on the left and my Navbar.Brand is on the far right. Since my toggle opens an offcanvas from the left hand side, I wanted the toggle button to be on the left. However, I want my Navbar.Brand to either be centered or left-aligned. I am new to react-bootstrap so apologizes for the dumb question.

[image]

Here is the current code:

```js
<Navbar
        key="md"
        collapseOnSelect
        className="sm md"
        expand="md"
        bg="dark"
        variant="dark">
  <Container fluid>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="offcanvasNavbarLabel-expand-md" />
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home">
            <img
              alt=""
              src={Logo}
              width="30"
              height="30"
              className="d-inline-block align-top"
            />
            My App
          </Navbar.Brand>
  </Container>
</Navbar>
```

I have tried adding the following `className` values to Navbar.Brand and on `NavBar` but have not gotten what I wanted:

- `justify-content-center-md`
- `justify-content-center`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either want `justify-content-start` (for left-alignment of the brand), or add an empty third element and use `justify-content-between` (for center alignment). This would probably go on the container, not the navbar.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#justify-content